# If mobile 3G checks Internet every 30 min, how come push messages come immediatelly?

Tags: android, push-notification, 3g

When a device is using the mobile Internet (3G, 4G), it connects to Internet every 30 minutes. This can be seen with emails coming in a bunch instead 1 by 1 like when a device is on wi-fi (among other things).

How come that push-messages for chat apps (hangouts, whatsapp, viber,...) come immediately?

I actually noticed that only Skype messages do not come immediately when I am on the mobile data connection. Others come instantly.

Comment: I just read the GCM documentation and it only mentions ~"if the device is online [an active connection to GCM] it'll send, else the GCM connection server will queue the message and try again later" but doesn't mention any details about this "active connection".

Comment: ah I didn't read much documentation because I just found that it uses a persistent XMPP connection (API 8 +): https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html

Comment: `it connects to Internet every 30 minutes. This can be seen with emails coming in a bunch` **NO**. eMails are coming in lots because **you** set the `refresh frequency of your eMail client to 30 min` (maybe it's the default - I set it to 1 hour). **The device is always connected**.

Comment: @DerGolem I think that mobile data rule will override any check interval and move it to minimum of 30 minutes. So if you set to "check every 5 min", it will be overridden to "check every 30 min". PS. my email check interval is between 5 and 15 min.

Comment: Yes, I guess so. But not if you are under WiFi, I guess again. But, OK, you were asking about 3/4G. You won. ;)

Comment: @DerGolem Yes, under wi-fi there are not such rules. But we all are guessing here as I could not find any docs on this topic. It's always vague and I-read-on-stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When a device is using the mobile Internet (3G, 4G), it connects to Internet every 30 minutes. This can be seen with emails coming in a bunch instead 1 by 1 like when a device is on wi-fi (among other things).

That just means that those apps happen to be pulling down data every 30 minutes, whether via `AlarmManager` or `JobScheduler` or `SyncManager` or whatever. They could just as easily set their `AlarmManager` polling period to be 27 minutes, or 2.7 minutes, or 27 days.

> How come that push-messages for chat apps (hangouts, whatsapp, viber,...) come immediately?

On a Play Services ecosystem device, either they are using GCM (which maintains an open socket connection), or they are using their own GCM-workalike (which maintains an open socket connection for however long they can keep their service running), or they are using something like `AlarmManager` with a small polling period (which is really bad for the battery, but that doesn't stop people).

On a Kindle Fire, they might be using Amazon equivalents of GCM, etc.

What makes mobile data interesting is that incoming packets on an open socket connection will wake up the CPU. From there, the apps for which those packets are destined can grab a `WakeLock` to be able to have time to process those packets. WiFi sockets are usually torn down around the time when the CPU goes into sleep mode, in part because usually the WiFi radio itself usually goes into a sleep mode around the same time, to conserve battery.

> I actually noticed that only Skype messages do not come immediately when I am on the mobile data connection.

Skype might not use GCM for competitive reasons. I'm a bit surprised that they aren't using their own workaround GCM-like service (e.g., MQTT-based).

Comment: Learned again something today. Thanks for your effort to write this down. What i do not understand though is  `incoming packets on an open socket connection will wake up the CPU.`. Where do they come in if the CPU is at sleep?

Comment: @greenapps - in most (all?) phones the GSM/UMTS radio functions are controlled by a different processor than the main CPU. The processor is usually called a 'Baseband processor'. Hence it is possible, and even normal, for the 'application' CPU to be asleep while the baseband processor is awake and receiving/sending data. The two processors can talk to each other to share and transit data etc.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I was already thinking of some kind of interrupt from an UART. Wel nearly...